# Question about different versions of Wolfenstein Youngblood

Tags: steam, version-differences, wolfenstein-young-blood

I have two possible version available for purchase on Steam:

[image: Steam store page for wolfenstine]

I assume the ~$50 version gives me the english version + the buddy pass.

On the other hand the ~$40 version gives me the english + german version but no buddy pass?

It just looks weird because looking at the packet information for the english + german version it looks like the $50 version is included:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now bought the Deluxe Version and even if it doesn't say it, this version contains both the international and the german version of the game.

Secondly I agree with Anne Kate and the bundle probably doesn't contain the deluxe version and the higher price shown is only a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

From the images you posted and from looking at the two versions on steam I would say it is a mere mistake that it shows the price of the deluxe edition. I think the bundle comes with the German and international base version. And there is a separate option to buy the international version as a deluxe edition, with the buddy pass. Either way, I would suggest opening the international one from within the bundle's page (second screenshot) and check which version it is.

Comment: Opening the internation one from within the bundle's page leads to the first screenshot. But you are probably right and it's just a mistake in the bundle about the price.